# Concatenating multiple values from a field to appear in a single cell

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join

There are 3 tables involved - **PEOPLE** (learners) and **PEOPLE_UNITS** (enrolments), and  **UNIT_INSTANCE_OCCURRENCES** (course detail).

```
 select distinct

 p.PERSON_CODE "upn",
 p.FORENAME "firstName",
 p.SURNAME "lastName",
 pu.UNIT_INSTANCE_CODE "Classes"

 from PEOPLE p   
 inner join  PEOPLE_UNITS pu    on pu.person_code = p.person_code           
 inner join UNIT_INSTANCE_OCCURRENCES uio   on uio.uio_id = pu.uio_id

 where pu.CALOCC_CODE = 2324
 and pu.UNIT_TYPE = 'R'
 and pu.PROGRESS_STATUS in ('A','F')
 and uio.status = 'ACTIVE'
 and p.FES_STAFF_CODE is NULL
 and p.IS_ACTIVE = 'Y'
 and uio.OWNING_ORGANISATION = 'BSK'

 order by p.SURNAME, p.FORENAME
```

The above is a basic version of the query I'm using (additional fields which aren't relevant to the issue have been removed), and will return one row per learner when the learner has only a single course (class) enrolment.
The issue comes when there are multiple enrolments per learner.

See below the first 10 rows of the output. You can see that for learners with upn 511812 and 472479 there is just a single row as they only have one class enrolment. The other learners all appear on multiple rows as they are enrolled on more than one class.

| upn | firstName | lastname | Classes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 511812 | Amal | Abdelkerim | BS4208LG |
| 516708 | Adil | Abdellatief | BS0071LG |
| 516708 | Adil | Abdellatief | BS0082LG |
| 511994 | Shabaaz | Abdool-Carrim | BS0081LG |
| 511994 | Shabaaz | Abdool-Carrim | BS0082LG |
| 417436 | Asma | Abid | BS0085PS |
| 417436 | Asma | Abid | BS0139LG |
| 516236 | Widad | Abouchakra | BS0071LG |
| 516236 | Widad | Abouchakra | BS4208LG |
| 472479 | Doaa | Aboudallah | BS0139LG |

I require the data to appear as below, with the class enrolments concatenated with a semicolon separator.

| upn | firstName | lastname | Classes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 511812 | Amal | Abdelkerim | BS4208LG |
| 516708 | Adil | Abdellatief | BS0071LG;BS0082LG |
| 511994 | Shabaaz | Abdool-Carrim | BS0081LG;BS0082LG |
| 417436 | Asma | Abid | BS0085PS;BS0139LG |
| 516236 | Widad | Abouchakra | BS0071LG;BS4208LG |
| 472479 | Doaa | Aboudallah | BS0139LG |

I have attempted using multiple subqueries which point to the people_units table, with each stipulating that the enrolment returned should not be equal to the previous one. However this resulted in the duplication of rows.
I also attempted a 'Stuff' command, but this retuned values in the classes field which don't exist as course codes in our system.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Google `STRING_AGG()`. Your should find many examples that use this function together with `GROUP BY` to achieve similar results.

Comment: And lose the `DISTINCT`. It is a bad habit to add DISTINCT to a query without understanding where duplicate data is coming from and fixing the source. Too often, DISTINCT may appear to improve the results, while it is actually hiding a deeper problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because you added some testdata:

```sql
select upn, firstname, lastname, STRING_AGG(classes, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Classes)
from (
    VALUES  (511812, N'Amal', N'Abdelkerim', N'BS4208LG')
    ,   (516708, N'Adil', N'Abdellatief', N'BS0071LG')
    ,   (516708, N'Adil', N'Abdellatief', N'BS0082LG')
    ,   (511994, N'Shabaaz', N'Abdool-Carrim', N'BS0081LG')
    ,   (511994, N'Shabaaz', N'Abdool-Carrim', N'BS0082LG')
    ,   (417436, N'Asma', N'Abid', N'BS0085PS')
    ,   (417436, N'Asma', N'Abid', N'BS0139LG')
    ,   (516236, N'Widad', N'Abouchakra', N'BS0071LG')
    ,   (516236, N'Widad', N'Abouchakra', N'BS4208LG')
    ,   (472479, N'Doaa', N'Aboudallah', N'BS0139LG')
) t (upn,firstName,lastname,Classes)
group by upn, firstname, lastname
ORDER BY lastname, firstname, upn
```

STRING_AGG allows aggregating the strings into a CSV.

If you're on older sql server you can use a bit more obtuse version:

```sql
WITH DATA AS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    (
    VALUES  (511812, N'Amal', N'Abdelkerim', N'BS4208LG')
    ,   (516708, N'Adil', N'Abdellatief', N'BS0071LG')
    ,   (516708, N'Adil', N'Abdellatief', N'BS0082LG')
    ,   (511994, N'Shabaaz', N'Abdool-Carrim', N'BS0081LG')
    ,   (511994, N'Shabaaz', N'Abdool-Carrim', N'BS0082LG')
    ,   (417436, N'Asma', N'Abid', N'BS0085PS')
    ,   (417436, N'Asma', N'Abid', N'BS0139LG')
    ,   (516236, N'Widad', N'Abouchakra', N'BS0071LG')
    ,   (516236, N'Widad', N'Abouchakra', N'BS4208LG')
    ,   (472479, N'Doaa', N'Aboudallah', N'BS0139LG')
    ) t (upn,firstName,lastname,Classes)
)

select upn, firstName, lastname
, STUFF((SELECT ';' + classes from DATA d WHERE d.upn = dd.upn order by classes FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
from DATA dd
group by upn, firstname, lastname
order by lastname, firstname, upn
```

The XML Path thing creates an fake xml string that starts with ; and contains list of classes. To remove the starting ';', one usually uses STUFF function